# Screen become dimmer when the screen object with dark background grows bigger

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [deactivate dynamic contrast on dell xps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195347/deactivate-dynamic-contrast-on-dell-xps)

I have this funny issue where my screen will goes dimmer, when the window with dark background grows bigger. In the reverse, my screen will goes brighter when majority of the screen have white background.

I am using it with Dell XPS 15z on ubuntu 12.04.